# there is any ubuntu specific action (i.e. command, install package ...)

Tags: 12.04, dependencies

i wonder there is "only" ubuntu specific action (i.e. command, package ...)

for example package "A" is installable for ubuntu but can't on Cent OS, Debian and Fedora.

thanks your answer.

Comment: Could you try to explain/describe your question a bit more detailed?

Comment: for examle, rm command is only used ubuntu environment. impossible on Cent OS.

Comment: The `rm` command is not Ubuntu-specific, should work on all Linux distributions.

Comment: but most unix system ... i can't found action (or package) which used only ubuntu..

Comment: yes i know. therefor i can't found ..

Comment: rm will somehow example, searching for something that works only ubuntu like it.

Comment: Again - it is - at least for me - still unclear what you are looking for. Try to edit your question and add as much description as possible to make it easier for us to help you ;)

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
sorry my english does not fluent ...

i want search things .. that available only ubuntu 

but most unix system shares these commands, packages ...

for example , in CentOS using yum, but "yum" is not available in ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know every Linux distribution package, use search engine to find the package you want. Because every Linux has different package name for the same program on different distro. For instance on Ubuntu you need to install GCC compiler and development tools using `apt-get install build-essential` but on CentOS you use `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`. Both command install the same program but have different name on each Linux distro. I hope it helps.